# Accessing data members shadowed by parameters

Tags: c++, naming-conventions, function-parameter

In Java you can access variables in a class by using the keyword `this`, so you don't have to figure out a new name for the parameters in a function.

Java snippet:

```
private int x;

public int setX(int x) {
  this.x = x;
}
```

Is there something similar in C++?  If not, what the best practice is for naming function parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to access members via `this`, it's a pointer, so use `this->x`.

Comment: thanks, I found the answer too when google. hehe took me like 1min compared to 2-3min to write down the question...

Comment: Lesson learned then, eh? ;) Never underestimate the search button.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Example {
    int x;
    /* ... */
public:
    void setX(int x) {
        this->x = x;
    }
};
```

Oh, and in the constructor initialization list, you don't need `this->`:

```
Example(int x) : x(x) { }
```

I'd consider that borderline bad style, though.

Comment: me too, kinda reminds me the ternary ifs, i.e. hard to remember how to write.

Answer (score 0):

```
private int x;

public int setX(int newX) {
  x = newX;
  return x;  //is this what you're trying to return?  
}
```

In most cases, I will make a 'set' function like this void IE

```
public:
void setX(int newX) {
  x = newX;
}
```

Comment: no I want to set the data member with the value from the parameter. Anyway I figure out that you need to write `this->x = x;`

Comment: Uh, I **am** setting the data member to the value of the parameter.  Doing this->x is unnecessary.  However, I'm glad you learned how to use the 'this' pointer correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on coding conventions.

From Google's [C++ style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml):

```
void set_some_var(int var) { some_var_ = var; }
int some_other_var_;
```